# Fast algorithm for finding parity of an RNS number

Tags: algorithm-design

Does anybody have a library of fastest parity finding algorithms in RNS representation? By parity I mean $x \bmod 2$ where $x$ is the number between $0$ and $N=\Pi m_i$ and all moduli are odd.

I have found a fast algorithm, but since it is quite simple, I need to check whether it pre-exists or not. I found a reference in a 2009 paper mentioning a 1991 algorithm for mixed radix based on moduli reconstruction that shows more or less the same logic.

To the request of Maarteen Bodewes, the paper I found is
"[An O(n) Residue Number system to Mixed Radix Conversion Technique](https://doi.org/10.1109/ISCAS.2009.5117800)" (alternate [source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221375916_An_On_Residue_Number_System_to_Mixed_Radix_Conversion_Techniquepb24iOiJwYWdlSGVhZGVyIn19)).
The set of equations (2) in the paper is akin to the formula I found. Strangely enough I skim read the paper 6 months ago not understanding where that formula came from, then reading another paper that presented a lookup table that showed the parity with the number and its decomposition, I told myself that since the parity can be found by parsing the LUT, you can find faster way to parse the LUT. Presently it was, say you have 5 prime moduli 1) the parity of any number up to the biggest modulus $m_5 -1$ is the parity of the number modulo the biggest modulus. Then you can cross all the $ k\times m_5\times m_4+r_5$ to find one decomposition having the same $r_4$ in the LUT, then you cross all the multiples of $k'\times m_5\times m_4 \times m_3 + r_3$ and so on.

Here is the algo:

```
pub fn parity_find( x:DoubleInteger )->(u32,u32,u32,u32,u32)
    {
    let k_1 = (INVP5MODP4*(P4_D + x.r_4 - x.r_5))%P4;
    let k_2 = (INVP5P4MODP3*(P3_D+ x.r_3 - x.r_5 )+k_1*PRODUCT3)%P3;
    let k_3 = (INVP5P4P3MODP2*( P2_D + x.r_2 - x.r_5 )+ k_1*PRODUCT2_1+k_2*PRODUCT2_2 )%P2;
    let k_4 = (INVP5P4P3P2MODP1*(P1_D + x.r_1 -x.r_5 ) + k_1*PRODUCT1_1+k_2*PRODUCT1_2 + k_3*PRODUCT1_3 )%P1;

    let parity= (x.r_5+k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4)&1;

    (parity,k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4)
}
```

Comment: There are two meanings for "parity of $x$": it can be $x\bmod 2$, or the XOR of all the bits in the binary PNS representation of $x$. For $x=2$, the first is $0$, the second is $1$. Also: if one of the moduli $m_i$ in the [RNS representaiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) is even, the first kind of parity is easy to find as $x_i\bmod 2$.

Comment: @fgrieu I mean x mod 2 where x is the reconstructed number, all my moduli are odd, otherwise it's pretty hard to do a right shift.

Comment: This may be better suited for [math.se]. If you want I can check for that, but I would like you to check & validate my edits and provide the reference to the paper you've found.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-modelection Up to you but RNS representation is relevant in cryptography. For example in homomorphic encryption since computation is demanding, you need a fast way to do operations. The RNS representation is suited for some operations, but not for others. As far as I understand, if one modulus is a power of 2 (or maybe just even) it's easy to detect parity and right shift but then it becomes hard to compare two numbers because the subtraction doesn't provide any information about crossing the N modulus. If you only have odd moduli then right shift is hard but you can compare.